How to show border around the parent and its expanded child rows in AG grid Angular?
When I click on arrow next to group name, I need to expand its child with border around them and no border between rows in AG grid Angular.
could you please help me, how can I do that?

I need help for changing the style of Ag grid when click on arrow of group name in Angular and expand items.
